# Setting same height for all cards in Horizontal layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-material, mean-stack

I have a horizontal layout in which I have 3 md-cards. Each card has different content in it. The problem is, based on the amount of content in each card, the card's height changes.

What I am trying to do is make the last 2 cards be the same height as the very first card (which has alot of content).

I have tried setting them layout="column" with flex as suggested in another post but it hasn't worked for me.

How can I fix it?

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNJYrp

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp" xmlns:width="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
</head>


<body layout="column">
<!-- ANGULAR MATERIAL DEPENDENCIES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<!-- ANGULAR MATERIAL DEPENDENCIES END-->


<md-content>
<div ng-controller="StudentRegisterationController">

    <md-content class="title-margin-top">
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">

            <md-card id="mainCard" flex="45">
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <img class="profile_image" src="/images/ic_account_image_placeholder.svg" aria-label="android ">
                </div>
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="First Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Last Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Home Address"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Contact Number"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Doctor Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Doctor Number"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="90">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Allergies"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container style="margin-left: -18px" class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Age"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <div flex="40" layout="row" layout-align="start center" style="margin-left: -18px">
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Birth Date"
                                       md-open-on-focus>
                        </md-datepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container style="margin-left: -18px" flex="40">
                        <label>Age Group</label>
                        <md-select required ng-model="ageGroup" ng-change="fetchObservationsListFromServer()">
                            <md-option ng-value="ageGroup" ng-repeat="ageGroup in ageGroupList">{{ ageGroup }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <div flex="40" layout="row" layout-align="start center" style="margin-left: -18px">
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Registration Date"
                                       md-open-on-focus>
                        </md-datepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--<div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <span flex="5"></span>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="23">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Allergies"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="23">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Doctor Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="23">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Doctor Number"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="5"></span>

                </div>-->
            </md-card>

            <md-card flex="35">
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Father First Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Father Last Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Mother First Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Mother Last Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Guardian First Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Guardian Last Name"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Father ID Card"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Mother ID Card"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Parent's Email Address"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
            </md-card>

            <md-card flex="20">
                <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Child ID"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>

                    <span flex="10"></span>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="40">
                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Password"
                               ng-model="bookName"
                               enter-pressed=""/>

                        <div ng-messages="$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
            </md-card>
        </div>

        <div class="title-margin-top" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" flex="none" type="submit"
                       ng-click="onSubmitClicked(myForm)">Submit

                <md-tooltip md-direction="left">
                    Send data to server
                </md-tooltip>
            </md-button>

            <span flex="2"></span>

            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" flex="none" type="submit"
                       ng-click="onSubmitClicked(myForm)">Delete

                <md-tooltip md-direction="left">
                    Delete From Server
                </md-tooltip>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
</md-content>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/newCode/accounts/Controller_StudentRegisteration.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Javascript:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("myapp", ['ngMaterial']);

mainApp.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').foregroundPalette[3] = 'rgb(83, 109, 254)';
});

mainApp.controller('StudentRegisterationController', function($scope, $http, $mdToast, $log) {
    $log.log(" STUDENT REGISTRATION");
});
```

CSS:

```
.profile_image{
    min-width: 36px;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply apply following CSS Rules on the parent container

```
.layout-row{

    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;

}
```

Comment: But this will affect the layout-row everywhere in the whole website. I want it to take affect only in the specific page. Please excuse my illiteracy in css

Comment: Give that element a different class name and then apply the css to that class name..

Comment: This works for the height perfectly fine. But now the last item in the row is not stretching properly in width. This looks like some issue with the flex but I am not able to find a solution.